# symfony2 relative directory routes from command

Tags: symfony, directory, routes, command, symfony-console

I'm facing a little trouble with the relative directories from command line.

I have created a command (php app/console generate:command). With this command I need to delete some files in the "web/myFolder" directory of the project.

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {     
        //$directorio = 'myFolder'; /*Do not work*/           
        $directorio = '\XAMPP\htdocs\MiProject\web\myFolder';
        $files  = scandir($directorio);

        foreach($files as $f){ /*do something*/ }
}
```

From the command, I have to write the complete directory from D:/ so I don't have a relative directory from the symfony project, like I do in any Controller.  Is there any solution to use a relative directory from the project folder?

With a non relative directory, I should replace this directory when put the project on a production server. So I should change it many time between test and production environment.

Lot of thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the predefined parameters like `kernel.root_dir` that usually point to the dir where the AppKernel file is locate (`<project_root>/app`).

So simply access to the params located in the container, as example

```
// From controller
$this->getParameters('kernel.root_dir');
```

or more generally:

```
// from service/command
$this->container->getParameters('kernel.root_dir');
```

So in your case should be:

```
$directorio = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../‌​web/myFolder';
```

some info [here in this article](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-fundamentals/parameters.yml-kernel.root_dir).

Hope this help

Comment: Works perfectly :) 
Thanks Matteo

Comment: But you should change the container param by:
$directorio = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/myFolder'
:) :)

Comment: Symfony 3.3 also adds `%kernel.project_dir%`, which points to the directory that contains web, app and others - avoiding the addition of `/..`  to a path